# Is there some way to speed up requests and/or timrout errors when using the python requests library?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, python-requests

I am doing an assignment to send requests to 1000 specific websites (some of which seem to no longer exist) in Python (3) with the HEAD method and report statistics about their response headers.  The script has to finish in five minutes.  Obviously you can make requests take less time by reducing the timeout, but the more you reduce the timeout the more timeout errors there are, and catching them seems to be very expensive.  For example, when the timeout was 0.3 seconds there were 700 good requests and 300 timeout errors, and the total time spent catching the timeout errors was by itself greater than five minutes.  Reducing the timeout does reduce the time to catch each timeout error, because requests has to wait for the timeout before throwing the error, but the number of timeouts also increases.  I was only able to get the total time spent catching timeout errors below five minutes at timeout=0.05 and timeout=0.03, but the total time including the time spent on requests was still greater than five minutes.  timeout=0.02 resulted in only 20 sites being reachable with a total error handling time of 5:17, and timeout=0.01 resulted in no sites reachable.  The person who gave the assignment insists that it is possible, so I must be doing something wrong.  I tried using a requests.Session object but that didn't result in any noticeable speedup.  What else can I do to speed things up?

Comment: Are you allowed/supposed to use threading? A simple `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` could likely be used to parallelize your queries so you're not stuck waiting on the slowest server; its `map` method would make it very easy.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is to use asynchronous HTTP requests. But in order to ethically answer this question I must insist on a low limit per domain for simultaneous requests, otherwise you can overload servers (and get blacklisted).

Below is an (untested) example implementation using `aiohttp` that supports a configurable number of maximum parallelism as well as maximum parallelism per domain.

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from collections import Counter

NUM_PARALLEL = 64
MAX_PARALLEL_PER_DOMAIN = 4
TIMEOUT = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=60)



async def fetch_url(url, session):
    try:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            # Whatever you want.
            return {
                "url": url,
                "status": response.status,
                "content-type": response.headers["content-type"]
            }
    except aiohttp.ServerTimeoutError:
        return {"url": url, "status": "timeout"}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"url": url, "status": "uncaught_exception", "exception": e}


domain_num_inflight = Counter()
domain_semaphore = {}


async def worker(urls, results):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=TIMEOUT) as session:
        while urls:
            url = urls.pop()
            domain = urlparse(url).netloc

            if domain_num_inflight[domain] == 0:
                domain_semaphore[domain] = asyncio.Semaphore(MAX_PARALLEL_PER_DOMAIN)
            domain_num_inflight[domain] += 1
            async with domain_semaphore[domain]:
                results.append(await fetch_url(url, session))
            domain_num_inflight[domain] -= 1
            if domain_num_inflight[domain] == 0:  # Prevent memory leak.
                del domain_semaphore[domain]
                del domain_num_inflight[domain]


urls = [...]
worklist = urls[:]
results = []
workers = [worker(worklist, results) for _ in range(NUM_PARALLEL)]
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*workers))
print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into those libraries.  If I am only hitting each URL once (like, assigning each worker a completely different list of URLS), is there a need for the semaphore?

Comment: @faiuwle The important part is that you only hit each *server* once. E.g. if your program requests stuff from a server many times per second you'll likely get blacklisted (or worse, reported to law enforcement).

Comment: These are plain domains, though, and all different - it's safe to assume that different domains are not on the same server, right?

Comment: @faiuwle No, but it's 'good enough'. If you were writing an industry-grade status-checker you would probably also include a separate IP resolution module and do more rate limiting based on IP address (block) as well.

Comment: Hi, I am still struggling with this.  When I use loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(...)) it immediately times out.  I even tried using wait_for to set a specific timeout of five minutes but it still times out immediately.  Is there some default timeout length that I have to override somehow?

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with the HTTP timeouts I was discussing before.  This is a asyncio timeout.

Comment: @faiuwle I don't know sorry. As I said I didn't test above code :) It shouldn't be far off though, good luck.

Comment: I figured it out, somehow the aiohttp calls were throwing asyncio timeout errors, I'm not sure why.  But catching them made it work.